# Weird raid problem

Tags: 16.04, raid

I have a server with ubuntu 16.04 with this raid configuration:

```
├─sda1    8:1    0   7,6G  0 part  
│ └─md0   9:0    0   7,6G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
└─sda2    8:2    0   924G  0 part  
  └─md1   9:1    0 923,9G  0 raid1 /
sdb       8:16   0 931,5G  0 disk  
├─sdb1    8:17   0   7,6G  0 part  
│ └─md0   9:0    0   7,6G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
└─sdb2    8:18   0   924G  0 part  
  └─md1   9:1    0 923,9G  0 raid1 /
```

```
md0 : active raid1 sdb1[2] sda1[0]
      7905280 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      
md1 : active raid1 sdb2[1] sda2[0]
      968720384 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 1/8 pages [4KB], 65536KB chunk
```

Well after removed /dev/sdb so I can clone it... then I added the disk back and then weird things starting to happen( I suspect this happen because I was editing a file while the sync process was not complete) like swap vim errors, many services failed on the sytem postfix, mysql, logging.

**I have erross on this services that indicates the system storage is full, but it's only about 85% on root partition.**

Then i tried a few things like removing the /dev/sdb, reboot the system,
apt-get clean
apt-get auto-clean
And it did not worked.

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm